Unable to bootstrap GNAT source build in UBI8
I am trying to compile GCC 8.5.0 from source in UBI8. Specifically, I want to build GNAT alongside it. Starting with the Docker image
redhat/ubi8
I install the required packages
dnf install -y gcc-gnat gcc-c++ gmp-devel mpfr-devel libmpc-devel
and download the source code of GCC 8.5.0 (same version as the system compiler) from the GNU website.
I unzip, make the build directory, and run configure from there. Most flags are irrelevant here, but I am adding ada to the build:
../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,ada ...
And I get this error:
configure: error: GNAT is required to build ada
Clearly gnat is installed:
# gnat --version

GNAT 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-21)
Copyright (C) 1996-2018, Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

So what's happening? gcc appears to not have been built with the ada frontend so it does not understand ada files. As seen here
# touch a.adb
# gcc -c a.adb

gcc: error: a.adb: Ada compiler not installed on this system

Which begs my question: is it at all possible to build GNAT using the system compiler? I was able to on CentOS7 since the package there had the frontend built in, however here it seemingly does not

Probably not. Looking at the description of the gcc-gnat package in EPEL:

Important: Please use 'gnatgcc' rather than 'gcc' for a GCC with Ada/GNAT
support because 'gcc' is unfortunately not really modular and was also
built without Ada/GNAT support by Red Hat (or a vendor of a 100% bug-for-bug
compatible drop-in distribution).

The package that provides a GCC with GNAT provides it as a standalone GCC compiler with Ada support (gnatgcc). The "normal" gcc executable is installed from a Red Hat repository. That compiler is (as of RHEL 8, link) build without Ada support.
The above can be verified in the output of the package installer. It shows that gcc-gnat is installed from epel and gcc is installed from ubi-9-appstream-rpms.
Note: Output shows the installation of gcc-gnat on UBI 9 as I couldn't get it installed on UBI 8. The reasoning seems the same though.
# dnf install -y gcc-gnat
[...]
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64  7.5 MB/s |  21 MB     00:02
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 openh264  5.9 kB/s | 2.5 kB     00:00
Dependencies resolved.
=======================================================================================
 Package                      Arch    Version               Repository             Size
=======================================================================================
Installing:
 gcc-gnat                     x86_64  11.4.1-4.el9          epel                   16 M
Upgrading:
 glibc                        x86_64  2.34-100.el9_4.2      ubi-9-baseos-rpms     2.0 M
 glibc-common                 x86_64  2.34-100.el9_4.2      ubi-9-baseos-rpms     313 k
 glibc-minimal-langpack       x86_64  2.34-100.el9_4.2      ubi-9-baseos-rpms      28 k
Installing dependencies:
 binutils                     x86_64  2.35.2-43.el9         ubi-9-baseos-rpms     4.6 M
 binutils-gold                x86_64  2.35.2-43.el9         ubi-9-baseos-rpms     736 k
 cpp                          x86_64  11.4.1-3.el9          ubi-9-appstream-rpms   11 M
 elfutils-debuginfod-client   x86_64  0.190-2.el9           ubi-9-baseos-rpms      39 k
 gcc                          x86_64  11.4.1-3.el9          ubi-9-appstream-rpms   32 M
 glibc-devel                  x86_64  2.34-100.el9_4.2      ubi-9-appstream-rpms   42 k
 glibc-headers                x86_64  2.34-100.el9_4.2      ubi-9-appstream-rpms  548 k
 kernel-headers               x86_64  5.14.0-427.18.1.el9_4 ubi-9-appstream-rpms  7.4 M
 libgnat                      x86_64  11.4.1-4.el9          epel                  1.3 M
 libgnat-devel                x86_64  11.4.1-4.el9          epel                  4.1 M
 libmpc                       x86_64  1.2.1-4.el9           ubi-9-appstream-rpms   65 k
 libpkgconf                   x86_64  1.7.3-10.el9          ubi-9-baseos-rpms      37 k
 libxcrypt-devel              x86_64  4.4.18-3.el9          ubi-9-appstream-rpms   32 k
 make                         x86_64  1:4.3-8.el9           ubi-9-baseos-rpms     541 k
 pkgconf                      x86_64  1.7.3-10.el9          ubi-9-baseos-rpms      45 k
 pkgconf-m4                   noarch  1.7.3-10.el9          ubi-9-baseos-rpms      16 k
 pkgconf-pkg-config           x86_64  1.7.3-10.el9          ubi-9-baseos-rpms      12 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 glibc-langpack-en            x86_64  2.34-100.el9_4.2      ubi-9-baseos-rpms     666 k


I thank you for the answer, and for providing a second set of eyes. Ultimately, since gprbuild truly does require the regular old gcc to work, I chose to build GCC on CentOS7 with Ada support, copy the installation folder to UBI8, and use that to build GCC on the newer OS. Only hiccup I ran into is that the version of MPFR changed, so I added a symlink from libmpfr.so.6 to libmpfr.so.4. Besides that, I now have a compiler natively built with Ada support, which works well enough for me.
